# search function from the database in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

This search function does not work yet. I don't know what the reason  is.
Can anyone help me to find the mistake?

This is in the **studentcontroller**

```
public function testsearch()
{
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    if($q != ""){
        $student = Student::where ( 'uniid', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get();
        if (count ( $student ) > 0)
            return view ( 'Searchstudent' )->withDetails ( $student )->withQuery ( $q );
        else
            return view ( 'Searchstudent' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
    }
    return view ( 'Searchstudent' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
}
```

and this is **Searchestudant.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
     <form action="/Searchstudent" method="POST" role="Searchstudent">

         <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"
                 placeholder="Search sickleave number"> <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                 </button>
             </span>
         </div>
     </form>
     <div class="container">
         @if(isset($students))
         <table class="table table-striped">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>unique id</th>
                     <th>student_id</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 @foreach($students as $student)
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{$student->uniid}}</td>
                     <td>{{$student->student_id}}</td>
                 </tr>
                 @endforeach
             </tbody>
         </table>
         @elseif(isset($message))
         <p>{{ $message }}</p>
         @endif
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the route

````
    ```Route::get('/searechstudent','StudentController@testsearch');  ```
````

The error shows when I run this function:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mismatched your routing between your blade form and your routes file.  In your **blade** you have called POST:

```
<form action="/Searchstudent" method="POST" role="Searchstudent">
```

With Laravel, it must match in the routing file.  In your web.php file (routing) you are accepting a GET response:

```
Route::get('/searechstudent','StudentController@testsearch');
```

Change the route to a POST response:

```
Route::post('/searechstudent','StudentController@testsearch');
```

Also, it may help you to look at the [PHP method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) `compact()` for your return variables from your controller in the `testsearch()` method - it keeps things consistent and easy to read.

Comment: I did the route (post) but the run now  show                                                                    (Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.)

Comment: Check your spelling for that.  In some places you note "searechstudent" - your route and your form action (`/Searchstudent`) are not the same.  Set your form to `/searechstudent` or fix the route to match

Comment: It is a spelling error.  Carefully check your form and your routes to make sure the form action and the routing are exactly the same.  Including *captials*.  The get/post thing will solve your problem, but only if you can find the spelling/caps error.

Comment: I change it all to search only small letters .. but it does not work.
can I get your email to send the pages to you?

Comment: No, keep the discussion here please.  Is your controller `StudentController`?  Is your action on your blade form `/searchstudent` ?   Is your web.php route: `Route::post('/searchstudent','StudentController@testsearch');`  Are they all spelled correctly?  Are they all caps / lower exactly the same?  A page not found error can only be a few things - and these are them.

Comment: now if I make it all (search) the run show error (MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message)

Comment: Back to the original problem.  Is your **form** for `search` showing POST?  Is your route showing post : `Route::post('/search','StudentController@testsearch');`

Comment: Hmm, looks like you have an incorrect spelling on the BLADE files too - look at this: `return view ( 'Searchstudent' )`  and your blade file is called **Searchestudant.blade.php** this will also cause the error.  Change one of those to match and test again.

Comment: ok , I change all the searchstudent to only small letters = (search) . and the balde and route is post .. if i write the command (php artisan route:list) my rote is not fond in the list!!  what can I do?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:cache` to refresh the cache.  But its not just small letters - check your **spelling** the blade file and the view in your method are **different**

Comment: the result of the command (Route cache cleared!)
ok, let me ask you if my first page is (Welcome.blade.php) is write the like to route to search page?                   (  <a href="search">search</a>    ) is correct .. right?

Comment: Yes to GET to the page, NOT to search.  The above requires a `Route::get('/search','StudentController@testsearch');` to get to the page to search. Then, from that page, the FORM requires a DIFFERENT route: `Route::post('/search','StudentController@testsearch');`

Comment: I mean here  ($q = Input::get ( 'q' );) into the controller . how can i get the input from the user?

Comment: That's a different question.  You have solved the routing issue and the spelling errors and the MethodNotAllowed exception.  Have you imported the class?  Try `\Input::`

Comment: public function testsearch(Student $student)
      {
      
       if($student!= ""){
        $student = Student::where ( 'uniid', 'LIKE', '%' . $student . '%' )->get();
        if (count ( $student ) > 0)
         return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $sickleave )->withQuery ( $student );

Comment: else
         return view ( 'search' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
          }
       return view ( 'search' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
      }

Comment: Too much for comments. Please mark this as correct for solving the original issue and ask another question - This is not easy to read the new issue throguh comments.

Comment: if I use\Input:: the result = (Class 'Input' not found)

Answer (score -1):

Be aware of your route address, it must be exact route as you called in form. Capital character is different with normal character

```
Route::post('/Searchstudent','StudentController@testsearch');
```

Comment: Use "php artisan route:list" to see all available routes, and check it with your form definition

Comment: Ooops,, I dose not found my route! what can I do now?

Comment: Look like your route definition is not running , something inside your router file ( on top of search route line ) is the couse. Maybe there is a return somewhere or ... . Upload your router file somewhere.